# How to transpile inline and external JavaScript in an HTML to ES5

Tags: javascript, html, babeljs, ecmascript-5, princexml

I have HTML files with `script` tags, containing either ES6 code or CDN links to modern JavaScript libraries (such as lodash). I need to have all the code in ES5, since it's required by the [Prince software](https://www.princexml.com/doc/js-support/) for converting them to HTML. Is there a way to solve this problem?